# Как забиндить пробел в tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как забиндить пробел в tkinter? Ну например левая кнопка это `canvas.bind("<Button-1>", OnClick)`,а движение с зажатой левой кнопкой это `canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", OnClick)`. Как сделать тоже самое, но на пробел?

Comment: я бы советовал добавить больше подробностей :)

Comment: Я бы посоветовал четко и внятно сформулировать свой вопрос, потому что сейчас ничего не понятно. Что значит «запрограммировать пробел»? Причем здесь «левая кнопка» (и левая по отношению к чему)? Причем здесь движение? Разбейте свою задачу на подзадачи, не смешивайте все в кучу и объясните так чтобы все поняли, что вы имеете в виду — тогда вам обязательно помогут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

root=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(root,width=400,height=300,bg='white')
def draw(event=None):
    canvas.delete(ALL)# clear canvas first
    canvas.create_oval(randint(0,399),randint(0,299),15,15,fill='red')
draw()
canvas.pack()

root.bind("<space>", draw)
root.mainloop()
```

Источник:  [How to bind spacebar key to a certain method in tkinter (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753978/7394871) от участника  [@twasbrillig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2213647/twasbrillig).

Comment: не забудьте адрес источника написать - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753793/how-to-bind-spacebar-key-to-a-certain-method-in-tkinter-python

Comment: @splash58 Сорри, забыл, я обычно добавляю ;)